# Get several values from the user in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4, qdialog

I am working on an application which uses the `QInputDialog` command to get a value from the user. The value is then used in several computation in the application.
Now I want to the able to read several values from the user before the computations are performed.

Any idea of what object from Qt should I use?

Thank you in advance,
madalina

Answer (score 4):

I would just create a custom QDialog (or heck just another screen in the application) to gather the required information, if it is several values.

Comment: So would I. QInputDialog is just a convenience to get a single value from user.